# Unexpected piped value 'undefined' on the View of component

Tags: angular

I often saw the question "Unexpected directive value 'undefined'..." but I get a different error for "Unexpected piped value 'undefined'...".

First I got this error when I tried to inject my custom @Directive to my component. I did not find a solution yet. But I tried to remove the pipe from my component and it worked.

So this works:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/app.component.html',
    pipes: [TranslatePipe],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

This works too:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/app.component.html',
    directives: [TranslateDirective],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

But this not:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/app.component.html',
    pipes: [TranslatePipe],
    directives: [TranslateDirective],
})
export class MyApp {}
```

Is it an open issue? Did I find a bug? Or is it simply not documented and I'm making something wrong?

Comment: Can you create a plunker repo?

Comment: hm on plnkr it works :-/
https://plnkr.co/edit/8ME4uT84FaCWeuedvb0t?p=preview

Comment: Hm ok - when I'm running `tsc` it compiles something that does not work. When I run `npm run tsc` it breaks with an error but the app works.

Comment: Might be related to minification.There are known issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the same error: install tsc >=1.8.0

Also angular2-beta.7 will help to solve the problem. But be carefull: es6-promise and rxjs has to updated as well.