# Angular 2 Error when trying to use a single file to import TS classes

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm getting the following error when loading my angular 2 application:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unexpected piped value 'undefined' on the View of component 'DashboardComponent'
```

The odd part is that if I uncomment this line and remove the "CustomPipe" reference from "appCore", it will work again:

```
//import {CustomPipe} from "../shared/customPipe"
```

This makes me wonder if somehow I am not importing/exporting classes correctly when using my "parent" export file "appCore.ts" or perhaps there is some issue with angular 2.

Am I doing something wrong?

[Example Project on Github](https://github.com/Sharpiro/InterviewPrep/tree/issues/import_export_issues/InterviewPrep.Angular2FirstLook/wwwroot/app)

CustomPipe.ts

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "angular2/core"

@Pipe({ name: "CustomPipe" })
export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform
{
    constructor()
    {
        console.log("created");
    }
    public transform(value: string, args: any[]): string
    {
        return "this value has been transformed into me via a custom pipe";
    }
}
```

appCore.ts

```
export * from "./dashboard/dashboardComponent"
export * from "./vehicles/VehicleListComponent"
export * from "./vehicles/VehicleComponent"
export * from "./shared/nestedComponent"
export * from "./interfaces/IVehicleService"
export * from "./shared/staticVehicleService"
export * from "./shared/VehicleService"
export * from "./shared/customPipe"
```

dashboardComponent.ts

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, Inject, Injectable, provide, OpaqueToken} from "angular2/core"
import {CustomPipe, IVehicleService, StaticVehicleService} from "../appCore"
//import {CustomPipe} from "../shared/customPipe"
import {NestedComponent} from "../shared/nestedComponent"
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx"
import {IVehicleServiceToken} from "../interfaces/IVehicleService"

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "./app/dashboard/dashboardComponent.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app/dashboard/dashboardComponent.css"],
    directives: [NestedComponent],
    pipes: [CustomPipe]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit
{
}
```

**Edit:**
[Here is a Plunker of the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7QdR0Fq0NKJl55qmHZh?p=preview):
Look at app/characters/character-list.component.ts line 5 & 6.  The plunk will not work, but if you uncomment line 6 and remove "CharacterService" from line 5, it will work.

Comment: What Angular version are you using? beta.16 already?

Comment: I was using beta 15, then updated to beta 16, along w/ everything else in my package.json as per @tibbus advice, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks alright. I tried to replicate in my app and whatever I do I cannot get your error.
I think you may have some outdated dependencies for Angular2, I will recommend to update every package to the latest supported.

A similar error can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687094/unexpected-piped-value-undefined-on-the-view-of-component) when using the wrong npm dependencies version.
[Unexpected piped value 'undefined' on the View of component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35687094/unexpected-piped-value-undefined-on-the-view-of-component)

Comment: I updated my GitHub solution to all the latest packages and the issue persists.  I also have the latest typescript version installed on my pc as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same strange error (angular-2-0.0.rc4).
My last import was my pipe and by moving up the import line, the error went away. I have no idea why. Have you tried moving up your pipe import line ?

I know it doesn't make any sense, but it fixed my problem.